# How to implement Python class in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following simple class implementation in Python. I would like to duplicate the functionality in F#...but I am not sure how...

```py
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def addEvidence(self,dataX,dataY):

        newdataX = np.ones([dataX.shape[0],dataX.shape[1]+1])
        newdataX[:,0:dataX.shape[1]]=dataX

        # build and save the model
        self.model_coefs, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(newdataX, dataY)

    def query(self,points):

        return (self.model_coefs[:-1] * points).sum(axis = 1) + self.model_coefs[-1]
```

So, in pseudo-code, the class looks like this:

```
Class()

    self.model_coefs = []
    self.residuals = []
    self.rank = 0

    self.addEvidence(dataX,dataY):

         x, y, z = f(dataX,dataY)

         self.model_coefs <- x
         self.residuals <- y
         self.rank <- z

    self.query(points)

         return ([self.model_coefs[i] * points[i] for i in points].sum()) + self.model_coefs[self.model_coefs.length]
```

And if there is an F-sharpy way to do this, great--The thing is, the entity is kind of a data-bin with a functional wrapper by design, so I'm not sure how it would be done with functions...

Anyhow, here is my try so far (I'm skipping the linear regression for now..)

```
namespace Learners

type LinearRegressionLearner() = 
    member this.ModelCoefficients  : int [] = [|0;0|]
    member this.Residuals : int[] = [||]
    member this.Rank = 0

    member this.addEvidence dataX dataY = "expletive"
    member this.query (points:int[]) = 
           points |> Array.iteri(fun i x -> x * this.ModelCoefficients.[i])
```

I get an error here: `points |> Array.iteri(fun i x -> x * this.ModelCoefficients.[i])`...I guess `this.ModelCoefficients.[i]` is a unit and doesn't match x, which is an integer??

Answer (score 3):

`Array.iteri` (as with all `iter` functions) expects a function that returns `unit` – yours returns `int`. Maybe you want [`Array.mapi`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340472.aspx) instead?

Comment: Aghhh! Ok, thankyou.  Any ideas on the least squares function corollary to `Numpy.linalg.lstsq()` in .NET? (Fslab?)

Comment: @bordeo - If you're asking a new question you should do it as a new question.

Comment: @bordeo : Not my area of expertise, sorry.